# Why does activeadmin show empty in the fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am doing a site using activeadmin. I have set up all the necessary fields up and set the form up with paperclip set up. My fields work for other resources and my model for the resource is set up.

When I add a new resource into the back in activeadmin I can save it but I get fields empty when you view it in the backend. The model is set up right too.

Model:

```
class Spotlight < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image, styles: {
        large: "600x450#",
        medium: "250x250#",
        small: "100x100#"
    }, :default_url => "/images/:style/filler.png"

end
```

activeadmin Spotlight.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Spotlight do

 form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :video
        f.input :image
        f.input :description
    end
    f.buttons
  end

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:spotlights => [:video, :image, :description])
    end
  end

end
```

ID  8
DESCRIPTION EMPTY
VIDEO   EMPTY
IMAGE   image

Is this a common issue found?

Cheers

Comment: I guess you have some code there, could you show it?

Comment: just edited the post now for you

Comment: can you give output of `Spotlight` from `rails c`?

Answer (score 2):

The params you receive from the form are in params[:spotlight] not in params[:spotlights] (notice the extra 's'). If it's not a typo in the post that should make sure the params are not filtered by strong_paramterers.

You can configure strong parameters to throw an exception when parameters get filtered out (advisable at least in development environment in my opinion). Otherwise you can find the messages in the log.

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

Comment: if I change to param[:spotlight] and then post the form again I get this error: Spotlight model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'

Comment: Are you sure you have the paperclip fields in your database "spotlights" table. For the error message you provide it looks like you don't have an "image_file_name" column there.

Comment: I have this class CreateSpotlights < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :spotlights do |t|
      t.text :description
      t.string :image
      t.string :video

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: I think I know now, I have not done an add attachment image to spotlight migration yet, which is why it cannot find it.